# Jax Rs to Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, spring-restcontroller

I have a rest end point written using JAX-RS

```
 import javax.ws.rs.core.Context

    @POST
    public Response something(@RequestBody MyOrderObject obj1,@Context MyObject obj2) {
    
    }
```

I want to write the above rest end point using Spring Rest.What should I replace the @Context in Spring Boot ?

```
@RestController
     class MyController
     {
    @POST
    public @ResponseBody something(@RequestBody MyOrderObject obj1) {

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Context` is Dependency Injection featured by JAX-RS. See also: https://dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-what-is-context

In your case just inject `MyObject object2` into your class as an attribue via `@Autowired` so you can use it later:

```
class MyController {

  private final MyObject object2;

  @Autowired
  public MyController(MyObject object2) {
    this.object2 = object2;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Should not autowire it directly, but use constructor injection.

Comment: Also context is [not directly analogous](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-httpheaders-and-uriinfo/) to Spring's autowired. It's more context-specific, if you excuse the pun.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas If i use `@Autowired MyObject object2` then won't itt work,If yes what should i use

Comment: In order `MyObject` can be injected it must be created/initialized in the first place. In general, you have a class annotated with `@Configuration` in which all the Spring Beans are created. So there you must also initialize `MyObject` so it can be injected into `MyController`.

Comment: You probably need to give more context about what MyObject is? Does it need request info?